# I bought the Tears of Veeshan Expansion for EverQuest 2 but I'm still unable to use the mercenary feature

Tags: everquest-2

This is my first expansion that I've purchased for this EverQuest 2. **Does the mercenary feature not come with this expansion?** For some odd reason I was thinking every expansion and feature always come with the latest expansion. Is this correct? Or do I need to purchase other expansions?

Answer (score 4):

If anyone stumbles across this question, looking for the answer. The expansion does not come with the mercenary feature, or any feature presented in the AoD** pack. You can no longer buy the AoD** pack and the features are sold on the marketplace for station cash.

** Age of Discovery